# How to extract end of data written inside a file in Java

Tags: java, android, file, randomaccessfile

I create an empty file with desired length in Android using Java like this:

```
long length = 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
String file = "PATH\\File.mp4";
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
randomAccessFil.setLength(length);
```

That code creates a file with desired length and with `NULL` data. Then  I write data into the file like this:

```
randomAccessFile.write(DATA);
```

Now my question is : I want to extract end of data written into the File. I have written this function to find end of data as fast as possible with binary search:

```
long extractEndOfData(RandomAccessFile accessFile, long from, long end) throws IOException {
    accessFile.seek(from);
    if (accessFile.read() == 0) {
        //this means no data has written into the file
        return 0;
    }
    accessFile.seek(end);
    if (accessFile.read() != 0) {
        return end + 1;
    }
    long mid = (from + end) / 2;
    accessFile.seek(mid);
    if (accessFile.read() == 0) {
        return extractEndOfData(accessFile, from, mid - 1);
    } else {
        if (accessFile.read() == 0) {
            return mid + 1;
        } else {
            return extractEndOfData(accessFile, mid + 1, end);
        }
    }
}
```

and I call that function like this to find end of data into the file:

```
 long endOfData = extractEndOfData(randomAccessFile, 0, randomAccessFile.length() - 1);
```

That function works fine for Files that their data begin with `NON-NULL` data and there is not any `NULL` data among data like this:

[image]

But for some some files it does not. because some files begin with `NULL` data as this:

[image]

What can i do to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is clear: You will never be able to find out how much data is written (or where the end of the content) is, when you are only searching for a NULL inside the file. The reason is that NULL is a byte with the value 0x00, which appears in all kinds of binary files (maybe not textfiles) and on the other side, your file is initialized with NULLs.

What you could do is for example to store the size of your data written to the file in the first four bytes of the file.
So when writing the DATA to the file, first write the length of it, and then the actual data content.

But I am still wondering why you don't initialize the file's size to the size you need.